# What is the correct way to collocate something average and a period of time?

Tags: collocation

I want to translate "average monthly salary" into English, in relation to a specific period which is "from September to April" (non-inclusive).

Will it be correct to just concatenate these two phrases? Or do I have to use a different preposition? Or maybe even change April to March and make it inclusive? (I think I could use "through" in that case, but I doubt I need to go that far, and I'm still not sure if that's the right way to do it.)

Update: if there's a difference between American English and British English in this instance, I need British English.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but "average monthly salary from September through April" sounds good to me.

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I asked. Thank you. So, "through" doesn't necessarily sound inclusive?

Comment: In American English, we'd go for "average salary from September through April, annualized".  But that's because Americans discuss gross salary annually, not monthly.  (Net salary, that is, take-home pay, might be discussed monthly)

Comment: On the other hand, to make any normalization interval work, just say "average salary from September until April" and then **state the normalizing interval in the value**: "Euros/week", "Pounds/month", "Dollars/year" etc

Comment: @Shrenostal: "Through" is absolutely inclusive. (And "to" also sounds inclusive in your example -- hence loading... and Ben Voigt's confusion -- though it could potentially be non-inclusive if the reader understands the significance of "April" and that significance implies non-inclusiveness.)

Comment: My understanding of the use of 'salary' is that it applies to an annual amount. *Wage* or *earnings* might be better usages for the phrase, e.g., "average earnings from September through April." To really nail it down adding the year(s) that these months refer to would be useful.

Comment: So many sources of ambiguity! September to April (non-inclusive) would be more naturally expressed IMO as 'October to March (inclusive)'. But, are you talking about when the salary was paid (month in hand) or when it was earned?
'X through Y' is an Am-E usage which would sound unnatural to Br-Eng ears, and while it would be understood, again you'd have to add 'exclusive/inclusive'.

Comment: Well, at least one thing is clear now, I really can just use an object like that and a period together, without using something like "for" instead of "from" between them. (And, by the way, it's including September but excluding April )